# insert query for adding product in prestashop

Tags: php, e-commerce, prestashop

I have an existing desktop application for managing my shop. Now Im making an online store, for that I have used prestashop. I have to add all the products from my old application to online shop. Also in future I will add new products through desktop application only. But when I add new product it should be reflect in the online shop.

Im planning to update the database from desktop application. For that I need to view the insert query for adding a product in prestashop. But I didnt find anything.Please guide me.

Thanks in advance,
iijb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a simple product creation, you will have to populate these tables :

- ps_product
- ps_product_shop (if prestashop version >= 1.5)

If you have combinations (E.g. Blue XL Tshirt, Black S Tshirt, ...) you need to populate these tables too (but this won't be easy) :

- ps_product_attribute
- ps_product_attribute_combination
- ps_product_attribute_shop

You have to look the database schema with phpmyadmin to see field names.

Anyway I suggest you to study how works modules such as oscommerce to prestashop, or magento to prestashop.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I run Prestashop 1.6, I believe that you will also have to enter the description in ps_product_lang. You may also have to make an entry of physical quantity available in ps_stock_available. For sure if you use advanced stock management.

Hope it helps!